# What does javac -version show?

Tags: java, javac

Even the [official documentation of javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)
says nothing about the -version option.

Comment: shows your java compiler version.

Comment: @erencan: by java you mean, jdk, jre, .... ?

Comment: javac stands for Java Compiler. JRE is not a compiler.

Comment: compiler is a part of jdk

Comment: @erencan : just extending....then wat does java -version show???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javac -version tells you about the JDK version. That is, it gives the information of Compiler.

Comment: @qualtar : java -version gives you JDK, JRE and JVM info. Javac -version just gives Java compiler/JDK info

Comment: It shows both JDK and JRE version, its more informational. If you run that cmd in command prompt you will get the idea.

Comment: @X86: what if i have different jre and jdk version??

Comment: @qualtar : if you compile using one version and run using another, it can lead to effects which cannot be said/anticipated. It might work, it might not. depending on what you are using in your code.

Comment: @X86 : Say i am not compiling anything. I have simply installed the jre6 and jdk7. What will java-version command show?

Comment: @qualtar : java version "1.6.0_45"   --> JDK version ...
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06) --> JRE Version..
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode) --> VM info. This is my java -version output.

Comment: nope..mine is same as yours, everything is listed as 1.6. While this is true for jre why is it showing 1.6 for jdk??? I have jdk 1.7.

Comment: @Qualter- Just check with your enviroment variables. If you are using windows OS, you can find it in System Properties Advance tab !

Comment: @Nasruddin : I have set the environment variable according to my jdk i.e. java 7. But still it shows 1.6 on executing java -version

Comment: Are you sure you have set classpath variable properly? I'm afraid that something is missing in System Properties variables. Just try to give proper path for JDK lib and bin folder of JAVA 7 that you have installed in your machine.

Comment: @Qualter : Just goto control panel and search java. You will be getting Java control panel. Click on Java tab then click view and check the version. Hope this will help you. :)
Thanks!

Comment: @qualtar - See the value of JAVA_HOME if you have set it. else see the path vaiable's value. check if you have both 1.6 and 1.7 installed and ur pointing to 1.6.

Comment: @X86 : I have set all my system properties (path and java_home) according to my jdk i.e. java 7.

Comment: @Nasruddin: on checking java version from control panel it shows java 6.

Comment: @qualtar - Then you've gotta a problem mate. Contact the OS vendors.

Comment: I doubt the correctness of this answer.  I believe `-version` simply give you the version of the JDK, but not anything related to "JDK Compiler Compliance Level".  It is also not reasonable: assume for 2 version of JDK, 1.6.0_11 and 1.6.0_12, they are two different version but they are still "compatible".  Things related to compliance level is `-source` and `-target`.  For example with `-target 1.4`, the result class is supposed to work with any Java 1.4 compliant runtime.  However this is ***not*** what `-version` is about.

Answer (score 2):

Official page does mention about it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Why you cannot find on the page is, `-version` is not available for `javac` until Java 6 I believe (I am sure it is not available in 1.4 and before).  That's why it is not showing on your page, which is `javac` ref page for Java 1.5. However, go to `java` command reference page of Java 1.5 and you should be able to find the `-version` switch.

Answer (score 1):

This command outputs your java compiler's version. In mine case it shows `1.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the official documentation for an **OBSOLETE** version of `javac` Java 5.  The `-version` option is documented in the `javac` manual entry for Java 6 and Java 7.

And in response to your question about what `-version` actually shows (for `javac` and `java`) the best answer is "unspecified" or "it depends on what version / platform you are using".  In practice, your best bet is to just try it for yourself.

---

If your reason for asking is that you want to extract some useful information about the Java platform from the version strings ... I recently tried searching for a web page that listed the version strings for the `java` command, and came up empty.  A better approach would probably be to write a tiny Java application to print out the relevant properties from the `System` properties object.  The javadoc for `System` lists a number of properties that are standardised.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand, both display the same; the version of Java that the tools are part of.

You can ASSUME that what one reports, the other will automatically also report and so it is overkill to have the option in both. Until the moment you encounter a machine where there are multiple versions of Java installed and you can compile something yet you can't run it. Displaying the versions of javac and java can then quickly tell you that the setup of the machine is messed up enough that different versions of Java are being used to compile and run. And then you thank the designers for adding it in.